# Apple App link does not open rather it asks for itunes

Tags: ios, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-app

I have uploaded an app on apple store named as "Pitelevision" but it is restricted to UAE and Pakistan store only.

I am unable to open my app link on browser

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pitelevision/id899221779?ls=1&mt=8

I am adding few images[image][image]

Why I am asked to install iTunes or open my link in iTunes?? As I remembered, the link was showing me a web page that contains my apple app description and details so what is wrong now?

To make myself very clear, I want this sort of page to be opened when i hit my above URL.
This is just sample link

https://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/track-your-gps-gsm-gprs-tracker/id633278299?mt=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you try to open in US appstore where it is not available. Try this instead:
   https://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/pitelevision/id899221779?mt=8

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when i click on "View on Appstore", will it always point me to US store or i can change store some where?

Comment: I think it is default value on iTunes Connect. I am not sure if there is any way to change it.